# Laravel breeze having an error upon inputting "npm install" in terminal

Tags: npm-install, npm-scripts

So I'm trying to install laravel breeze for the first time and having these error

E:\Path Directory: npm install

Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1

- npm install
- 

At line:1 char:1

- npm install
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
  ```

I tried reinstalling node and also tried in command prompt but I'm having "Access denied" error.